# Abrir archivo CSV en jupyter

Tags: python

cree un archivo .csv y cuando lo quiero cargar en Jupyter lo lee correctamente pero no me lo separa como un DataFrame. Estoy haciendo algo mal con mi código o el problema lo tengo en el archivo .csv? Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El separador default es la coma, en tu caso es el punto y coma. Agrega a `read_csv` el parámetro `sep = ";"`

Answer (score 1):

Solo agrega el parámetro de separación ya que el método read_csv tiene por default separación por comas para un archivo csv

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Trabajo.csv', sep=';')
```

Puedes leer algo sobre eso acá
https://riptutorial.com/es/pandas/example/21737/leer-archivo-csv